# Recover mini paper widget contents after update (2.3.3 to 2.3.4)

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, updates, app-widgets, data-recovery

I've updated my Galaxy S2 from 2.3.3 to 2.3.4 only to find that the mini paper widget is now broken.  Plenty of places on the web explain how to clear the data to get it working again, but is there ANY way to get that data data?  It must be stored on the phone somewhere...

Or perhaps it can be rolled back to 2.3.3 (unlikely).

Comment: What mini paper widget is this? Is it an app you've installed, or something Samsung added to the system?

Comment: It came with the phone, so I would assume Samsung?  If there is anything I can do to identify it let me know.